# I want to create path for different letters in svg image

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollmagic

I've recently come across the ScrollMagic library. And I'm trying to recreate thier signature animation on scroll (link :- http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/svg_drawing.html ). I want to add other alphabet in the svg using the paths .
I've provided their code which animates the word "magic" but I want to create my own alphabets using the path ... How should I proceed?

```html
<div class="spacer s2"></div>
<div id="trigger1" class="spacer s0"></div>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="350" height="200">
  <path id="word" style="stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-dasharray: 1009.23px; stroke-dashoffset: 1009.23px;" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" 
        d="M22.328,70.018c9.867-7.4,10.724,20.434,13.014,28.694c-0.08-9.105-1.308-31.463,11.936-31.886
          c11.313-0.361,17.046,19.368,16.367,28.098c-1.432-10.289,6.234-30.682,18.163-25.671c11.505,4.833,8.682,26.772,20.071,31.964      
          c13.06,5.953,14.854-8.305,19.734-17.017c7.188-12.836,4.933-15.417,29.6-14.8c-8.954-3.842-37.42,1.728-28.539,20.1
          c5.823,12.045,34.911,12.583,30.018-8.873c-5.385,17.174,24.01,23.104,24.01,9.123c0-9.867,3.816-15.937,16.034-18.5
          c8.359-1.754,18.982,4.754,25.9,9.25c-10.361-4.461-51.941-13.776-37.749,12.357c9.435,17.372,50.559,2.289,33.477-6.063
          c-2.871,19.008,32.415,31.684,30.695,54.439c-2.602,34.423-66.934,24.873-79.302,2.134c-13.11-24.101,38.981-36.781,54.798-40.941
          c8.308-2.185,42.133-12.162,25.88-25.587c-2.779,17.058,19.275,28.688,29.963,12.911c6.862-10.131,6.783-25.284,30.833-19.117
          c-9.404-0.429-32.624-0.188-32.864,18.472c-0.231,17.912,21.001,21.405,40.882,11.951"></path>
  <path id="dot" style="stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-dasharray: 44.2974px; stroke-dashoffset: 44.2974px;" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5"
        d="M247.003,38.567c-7.423,1.437-11.092,9.883-1.737,11.142c14.692,1.978,13.864-13.66,1.12-8.675"></path>
</svg>
    
<div class="spacer s2"></div>
    
<script>
  function pathPrepare ($el) {
    var lineLength = $el[0].getTotalLength();
    $el.css("stroke-dasharray", lineLength);
    $el.css("stroke-dashoffset", lineLength);
  }

  var $word = $("path#word");
  var $dot = $("path#dot");

  // prepare SVG
  pathPrepare($word);    
  pathPrepare($dot);

  // init controller
  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

  // build tween
  var tween = new TimelineMax()
    .add(TweenMax.to($word, 0.9, {strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone})) // draw word for 0.9
    .add(TweenMax.to($dot, 0.1, {strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))  // draw dot for 0.1
    .add(TweenMax.to("path", 1, {stroke: "#33629c", ease:Linear.easeNone}), 0);         // change color during the whole thing

  // build scene
  var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger1", duration: 200, tweenChanges: true})
    .setTween(tween)
    .addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin)
    .addTo(controller);
</script>
```